Where does FlightAware obtain the filed flight plans under the "Flight Data" section?
Visit the FlightAware page for a random flight, say https://www.flightaware.com/live/flight/QFA570
Now under the "Flight Data" section, sometimes we'll see an entry called "Route" with the flight's filed routing.
I've noticed that for flights operating to/from or passing through Australia and New Zealand, the full routing is revealed regardless of direction of flight.
This is in contrast to the situation for flights passing through the US, Canada and Mexico, where flights leaving these places will have the full flight routing available for viewing, but those heading to the US, Canada and Mexico will only reveal the sections of the routing inside their airspace.
i.e. the displayed route on FlightAware for a flight from LHR to JFK's route will start in US/Canadian airspace, whereas a flight from JFK to LHR will have the full route revealed, down to the STAR in London. To illustrate, have a look at these 2 FlightAware pages. BA117 operates from LHR to JFK, and BA116 the other way round.
https://www.flightaware.com/live/flight/BAW117
https://www.flightaware.com/live/flight/BAW116
Now there are some exceptions, notably https://www.flightaware.com/live/flight/VIR3, but the rule generally holds true.
For flights overflying these areas (e.g. from HAV to FRA), the sector which will have the flight first pass through US/Canadian/Mexican airspace will have the full routing revealed. So the full routing is revealed from HAV to FRA, but not from FRA to HAV, in similar fashion to the LHR to JFK situation.
For all other routes which don't fall into the abovementioned category, there is no "Route" entry.
I'm interested to know - where specifically is FlightAware getting this filed route data from? Can I access it and view it independently? Are there sources where I can get this information for flights outside the abovementioned regions?
I am particularly interested in routes in Europe and Asia, especially longer ones, as for shorter routes flights normally take standard routes which you can deduce with the high-altitude airways overlay in FlightRadar24 (if you have a better way of doing so, please let me know). Longer flights however will have their routings change pretty much every flight.
I've tried going into the EuroControl portal, checking various ADS-B websites, but to no avail. Initially I thought https://globe.adsbexchange.com/ might have the routing since it carries so much information but unfortunately not.
Thank you in advance for any help.

What a great question

One of the data sources used by FlightAware is ASDI. This data includes filed flight plans for airborne flights and also (near) future planned flights.
Although the Wikipedia page limits its description to ASDI as provided by the FAA, other ASNPs provide similar data using the ASDI protocols. Generally this data is available by specific arrangement with ANSPs and is not a publically accessible feed. I know that FlightAware does have specific arrangements with ANSPs other than the FAA to obtain this information.

Thank you for the information my friend. Will be reading up on this and seeing what I may potentially stumble upon.
